# Расширенная кастомизация iso файлов

Tags: iso-образ

Где я могу найти информацию насчет изменения iso-образа под свои нужды? Что-то вроде пресловутого авторана, или чего-то подобного, но более расширенного по функционалу. Может какая-нибудь документация Майкрософт? Ведь по сути iso-образ - это файл, следовательно он на чем-то написан и может быть изменен. Также возможно ли как-то реализовать подобную структуру внутри образа диска?

Про `UltraISO` и т.п. знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял вопрос. Надеюсь, наведет на нужные мысли:

Можно установить операционную систему, например `linux`, на флешку, и загружаться с нее. Такая флешка будет доступна для любых изменений как из самой ОС, установленной на нее, так и из другой ОС.